# django-autocomplete-light: comma selection using the MultipleChoiceWidget

Tags: python, django, django-autocomplete-light

How do i manage to use a key-selection in a form using the **autocomplete_light.MultipleChoiceWidget** ?

I would like to select entries of a m2m field by using the comma key intead of choosing it via mouseclick. I found the related paragraph in the [docs](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#using-yourlabsautocomplete-to-create-a-navigation-autocomplete) but i don't understand how to construct it.

**models.py**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True, null=True)

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
```

**autocomplete_light_registry.py**

```
autocomplete_light.register(Tag,
                search_fields=['name'],
                autocomplete_js_attributes={
                                    'placeholder': 'Insert additional tags',
                                            },
                widget_js_attributes = {
                                        'max_values': 3,
                                        }
                )
```

**forms.py**

```
    tag = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(Tag.objects.all(),
    widget=autocomplete_light.MultipleChoiceWidget('TagAutocomplete'),
    required=False)
```

[image: autocomplete_m2m]

The autocompletion works fine except that you have to click on the desired tag. I'm looking for a solution how to select an entry using a key like spacebar or comma.

Comment: Did you notice that you can select the item with Enter ? Why isn't that good enough ?

Comment: No, i didn't :) That's good, even if i still would like to choose the key myself :) thx

Comment: Keyboard navigation uses enter, tab and arrows by default. You can probably add your own shortcuts too.

Comment: I thought there would be a js_attributes i was missing when i started the question - really great module btw ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want entries separated by the comma caracter then you need to use an `autocomplete_light.TextWidget`. However, it doesn't work for relations, it will work only for `CharField` and the like.

`MultipleChoiceWidget` maintains a sane hidden select element. The select needs to contain `<option>` which have `value=the_foreign_key`. If this select was maintained by an input with a comma separated list of object titles, then a user could checkmate it by modifying a previously entered object name - not to mention that an object name change at the time of selection would checkmate the autocomplete as well.

Comment: extended my question. it works fine if i click on the entries i want to select. I'm just looking for a way to use a key (spacebar / comma) to select the entry instead of a click.